# Asset Pipeline Pre-Compile all asset folder sub directories

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, asset-pipeline, assets

I like to keep my assets highly organized, however, I am running into an issue with precompile.  It is not picking up the sub directories.  Here are the paths:

```
assets
>fonts
>images
>>backgrounds
>>home
>>icons
```

Everything works on dev, but prod = no go.  In my prod environment I already do:

```
 config.assets.enabled = true
  config.assets.compile = true
  config.assets.precompile += ['*.js', '*.ico', '*.png', '*.jpg']
  config.assets.initialize_on_precompile = true
```

And I am currently running the following function in my application.rb file:

```
   # Add All Asset Pipeline Sub Folders
    Dir.glob("#{Rails.root}/app/assets/images/**/").each do |path|
      config.assets.paths << path
    end
```

This is what I have been working with no, with not much luck.  I was hoping to dynamically pick up all directories created/changed etc with  few lines of code so I do not have to add them one by one.....

```
  # Add All Asset Pipeline Sub Folders
    Dir.glob("#{Rails.root}/app/assets/images/**/").each do |path|
      config.assets.paths << path
      config.assets.precompile += ['#{path}/*']
    end
```

Thoughts?

**Updated Solution**:

I ended up going with the following in my production rb:

```
  config.assets.precompile += ['*.js', '*.ico', '*.png', '*.jpg']
  config.assets.precompile += [ Dir["#{Rails.root}/app/assets/images/**/*"].reject {|fn| File.directory?(fn) } ]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
# Add All Asset Pipeline Sub Folders
Dir.glob("#{Rails.root}/app/assets/images/**/").each do |path|
   ..  # seems you include /assets/images sub directories, expand the path
```

---

Ruby command:

```
Dir.glob("#{Rails.root}/app/assets/images/**/")
```

returns directories, located inside

> /images

directory. I assume, that you push to precompiler images assets only. Has a sense? Replace it with:

```
 Dir.glob("#{Rails.root}/app/assets/**/")
```

Comment: What do you mean? Do you have an example? Adding the full paths work for "config.assets.paths << path" but the precompile needs it differently?

Comment: I ended up going with the following in my production rb:
  config.assets.precompile += ['*.js', '*.ico', '*.png', '*.jpg']
  config.assets.precompile += [ Dir["#{Rails.root}/app/assets/images/**/*"].reject {|fn| File.directory?(fn) } ]