# How to only use relative paths in Rails, instead of using the asset pipeline?

Tags: javascript, css, ruby-on-rails, asset-pipeline

I am trying to integrate components from multiple websites into my own Rails website. Their images, CSS files, and JavaScript files are numerous and scattered in deeply nested directories. If I copy their folders into the 'app/assets' folder, I will get something like this:

```
app/assets/website1/a/b/c/d/image1.jpg
app/assets/website2/e/f/g/style.css
app/assets/website3/h/i/j/k/custom.js
```

If I try to reference the above items with:

```
<img src="/app/assets/website1/a/b/c/d/image1.jpg">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/app/assets/website2/e/f/g/style.css">
<script src="/app/assets/website3/h/i/j/k/custom.js"></script>
```

respectively, they will not load at all. I would greatly prefer to use relative paths because using the asset pipeline would be a nightmare with such deeply nested directories. Is what I am describing even possible?

Comment: You can add nested subfolders to the precompile path: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22432460/asset-pipeline-pre-compile-all-asset-folder-sub-directories

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried disabling the asset pipeline in config/application.rb by adding the following line to it ?

```
config.assets.enabled = false
```

Havn't tested it. Let me know if it works.

Comment: It helped a few things load but most of the stuff is still broken. Thanks anyway.

Comment: Moving all of the referenced images into the app/assets/images folder, all of the referenced CSS files into the app/assets/stylesheets folder, and all of the referenced JavaScript files into the app/assets/javascripts folder helped a lot. But a lot of the images are still not showing up.

Comment: try precompiling the assets